# Provider and flutter_bloc setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, provider, flutter-bloc

I am using provider and flutter_bluc in my app. Right now I am struggling with this case: A new state is passed to BlocBuilder, which rebuilds part of the Widget Tree UI. What I want is to also update **my bottomNavigationVisibility, which extends ChangeNotifier.** I use this **bottomNavigationVisibility for updating another part of the widget tree.**

That way I could easily achieve good separation logic for my UIViews IMHO. However, right now I am always getting this error:

**setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.**

Here are the code samples:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bottomNavigationVisibility =
        Provider.of<ProviderBottomNavigation>(context);
    ...
 Container(
                height: 60.0,
                child: BlocBuilder<SoundsblocBloc, SoundsblocState>(
                    condition: (previousState, state) {
                  if (previousState is InitialSoundsblocLoading) return true;
                  return false;
                }, builder: (context, state) {
                  if (state is InitialSoundsblocLoaded) {
                    if (state.sounds
                        .where((sound) => sound.focused)
                        .toList()
                        .isEmpty) {

                      bottomNavigationVisibility.isVisibleT(false);
                    } else {
                      bottomNavigationVisibility.isVisibleT(true);
                    }
                  }

                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: listOfSounds.length,
                      ...
                })),
```

​

```
class ProviderBottomNavigation extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isVisible = false;

  bool get isVisible => _isVisible;

  void isVisibleT(bool val) {
    _isVisible = val;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

How should I change my code to update my ChangeNotifier from widget A, which is observed in widget B, after a particular bloc state was returned?

**Also, could I be wrong and using the Provider for separate UI parts with flutter_bloc is a bad combo**?

Comment: Instead of using BlocBuilder, you should use BlocListener. Because as the documentation says, BlocBuilder is purely for building Widget and BlocListener is for functionality. Once you change your logic inside BlocBuilder into BlocListener, I am pretty sure it will most likely work as intended. Also in addition, I don't know whether it's a bad combo or not :)

Comment: @FederickJonathan thanks, I solved it with BlocConsumer :) It has BlocListener under the hood.

Comment: yea.. technically what you need is 'listener property' whether via BlocConsumer or BlocListener itself.